# Repair PDFium crashes for old Android versions or include own library

Tags: android, pdfrenderer, android-native-library, pdfium, pdf-rendering

I have an Android app which uses the standard [`PdfRenderer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer) to render PDFs. It is working so far so good and I managed to get rid of the most of the errors in the app.

The only error I have no idea how to get rid of is:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7
#00  pc 00000000000be7e0  /system/lib/libpdfium.so (FPDF_CloseDocument+12)
```

It is happening in several variations (not only FPDF_CloseDocument) and produces up to 4% of crashes in daily sessions.
The problem is encountered on Android versions from 5 to 8 on various devices.

After some searching, it appears, that [`PDFium`](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/) library (on which [`PdfRenderer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer) is based on) had some bugs in earlier versions. That's why the problem is not appearing on Android versions 9 and 10.

So my practical task is to **get rid of 11 SIGSEGV crashes**.

Here I have the following ideas:

1. **Include the latest version of PDFium into my app.** Currently libpdfium.so is included to Android OS. Can I include the final corrected library into my app and use it? Where to find the libpdfium.so and how to use it in the app?
2. **Use an alternative PDF renderer.** I need to render a part of a PDF page in a desired zoom and resolution and I need a pretty loose license like MIT or Apache, so I don't need to open source of my project. I didn't find any appropriate, e.g. [MuPDF](https://www.mupdf.com/) requires to open source the whole your project, [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) is fully proprietary.

What way is better to get rid of 11 SIGSEGV crashes?

Comment: Do you compile your project on Android 4.1? I started to observe this issue on apps built with latest tools.

Comment: I use Android Studio 4.2 Canary. I tend to think it is Android OS version of the devices. Unfortunately I can't reliably reproduce the issue in my own environment, and only see it in Google Play crashes. So I can't research the issue properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your threading and make sure there is no concurrency issue, as per doc it's not thread safe:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer

Comment: This is a very good point. Actually PdfRenderer is created in several activities for different purposes: to display pages or thumbnails etc. So create-open-close in every single activity is synchronized, but not between activities. I would create a static variable / class for on the application level and would call its open-close from different activities. What do you think about this approach? Real practical test will take some time.

Comment: I have way less crashes, when I synchronised with lock usages of renderer.

Comment: After one week of beta test on ~3K devices this type of error is virtually disappeared! This was the correct solution! Thank you!